# finishする瞬間に他のアプリが一瞬表示されてしまう

Tags: android

1. ランチャーアクティビティからAccountManager経由で独自AccountAuthenticatorActivityを起動
2. 独自AccountAuthenticatorActivityでバックボタンが押されたら、認証をキャンセル
3. AccountManagerのコールバックでfutureがキャンセルされていたら、ランチャーアクティビティをfinish
4. アクティビティが消えるトランジションの後、一瞬 (それまでに起動していた) アプリの画面が表示される

という症状です。

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LaunchActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

バックボタンが押された時のコールバック: 認証をキャンセルする

```java
public class LoginActivity extends AccountAuthenticatorActivity {
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        setAccountAuthenticatorResult(null);
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
    }
}
```

AccountManagerのコールバック内でキャンセルを処理

```java
    mAccountManager.getAuthTokenByFeatures(mAccountType, mAuthTokenType, null, activity, null, null,
        new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
            @Override
            public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                Bundle bundle;
                try {
                    if (future.isCancelled()) {
                        eventBus.post(new LoginFailedEvent(true));
                        return;
                    }
```

ランチャーアクティビティを`finish()`

```java
public class LaunchActivity extends BaseActivity {
    // EventBus経由で受け取る
    public void onEventMainThread(LoginFailedEvent event) {
        if (event.isCancelled()) {
            finish();
        }
```

終了の仕方がおかしいなどあるでしょうか。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

これは[Nexus 5 + Android 4.4.3以降で起きる問題](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71067)のようです。

回避策として、`moveTaskToBack`で一旦アプリをバックグラウンドに回すようにしたら他のアプリは表示されなくなりました。

```java
public class LaunchActivity extends BaseActivity {
    // EventBus経由で受け取る
    public void onEventMainThread(LoginFailedEvent event) {
        if (event.isCancelled()) {
            // workaround for: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71067
            moveTaskToBack(false);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```